# Loss is not decreasing at all for RNN

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, torch, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I have already tried to change the weights initialization parameters, learning rate and the batch size and the activation functions to ReLu
Still no decrease in the loss
This is the code:

```python
import torch
import torchvision.datasets as dsets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np


no_time_steps = 28
input_size = 28
hidden_size = 30
output_size = 10
batch_size = 100
num_epochs = 2
learning_rate = 0.01
dtype = torch.DoubleTensor


# MNIST Dataset
train_dataset = dsets.MNIST(root='./data/',
                        train=True, 
                        transform=transforms.ToTensor(),
                        download=True)

test_dataset = dsets.MNIST(root='./data/',
                       train=False, 
                       transform=transforms.ToTensor())

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset,
                                       batch_size=batch_size, 
                                       shuffle=True)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset,
                                      batch_size=batch_size, 
                                      shuffle=False)

class RNN(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size,output_size,batch_size):
    super(RNN, self).__init__()
    self.input_size=input_size
    self.hidden_size=hidden_size
    self.output_size=output_size
    self.wxh=Variable(torch.randn(input_size,hidden_size).type(dtype)*0.1,requires_grad=True)
    self.whh=Variable(torch.randn(hidden_size,hidden_size).type(dtype)*0.1,requires_grad=True)
    self.why=Variable(torch.randn(hidden_size,output_size).type(dtype)*0.1,requires_grad=True)
    self.by=Variable(torch.Tensor(batch_size,output_size).type(dtype).zero_(),requires_grad=True)
    self.bh=Variable(torch.Tensor(batch_size,hidden_size).type(dtype).zero_(),requires_grad=True)

    self.mWxh= torch.zeros_like(self.wxh)
    self.mWhh= torch.zeros_like(self.whh)
    self.mWhy= torch.zeros_like(self.why)
    self.mbh= torch.zeros_like(self.bh)
    self.mby= torch.zeros_like(self.by)
    self.dwxh, self.dwhh, self.dwhy = torch.zeros_like(self.wxh), torch.zeros_like(self.whh), torch.zeros_like(self.why)
    self.dbh, self.dby = torch.zeros_like(self.bh), torch.zeros_like(self.by)

def hidden_init(self,batch_size):
    self.hidden={}
    self.hidden[0]=Variable(torch.Tensor(batch_size,hidden_size).type(dtype).zero_())

def tanh(self,value):
    return (torch.exp(value)-torch.exp(-value))/(torch.exp(value)+torch.exp(-value))

def parameter(self):
    self.params = torch.nn.ParameterList([torch.nn.Parameter(self.wxh.data),torch.nn.Parameter(self.whh.data),torch.nn.Parameter(self.why.data),torch.nn.Parameter(self.bh.data),torch.nn.Parameter(self.by.data)])
    return self.params

def grad_data(self):
    print(self.dwxh,self.dwhy)

def softmax(self,value):
    return torch.exp(value) / torch.sum(torch.exp(value))

def updatess(self,lr):
    for param, dparam, mem in zip([self.wxh, self.whh, self.why, self.bh, self.by],
                            [self.dwxh,self.dwhh,self.dwhy,self.dbh,self.dby],
                            [self.mWxh, self.mWhh, self.mWhy, self.mbh, self.mby]):
        mem.data += dparam.data * dparam.data
        param.data += -learning_rate * dparam.data / torch.sqrt(mem.data + 1e-8)                                                                                                                


def forward(self,inputs,batch_size,no_time_steps,labels):
    self.hidden_init(batch_size)

    inputs=Variable(inputs.type(dtype))
    self.output=Variable(torch.Tensor(no_time_steps,batch_size,self.output_size).type(dtype))

    for t in xrange(no_time_steps):
        if t==0:
            self.hidden[t]=torch.matmul(self.hidden[0],self.whh)
            #print 'time  ',t#,"Inputs",inputs[:,t,:],"Weights",self.wxh
            #print "hidden MATRIX",inputs[:,t,:]
            self.hidden[t]+=torch.matmul(inputs[:,t,:],self.wxh)
            self.hidden[t]=self.tanh(self.hidden[t]+self.bh)
            #print 'time  ',t#,"Inputs",inputs[:,t,:],"Weights",self.wxh
            #print "HIDDEN MATRIX",self.hidden[t]
        else:
            self.hidden[t]=torch.matmul(self.hidden[t-1],self.whh)#+torch.matmul(self.hidden[t-1],self.whh) 
            #print 'time  ',t#,"Inputs",inputs[:,t,:],"Weights",self.wxh
            self.hidden[t]+=torch.matmul(inputs[:,t,:],self.wxh)
            self.hidden[t]=self.tanh(self.hidden[t]+self.bh)
        #print 'time  ',t#,"Inputs",inputs[:,t,:],"Weights",self.wxh
        #print "############################################################################################"
        #print "hidden MATRIX",self.hidden[t]
        self.output[t]=self.softmax(torch.matmul(self.hidden[t],self.why)+self.by)
        #print "OUTPUT MATRIX",self.output[t]            
    return self.output
def backward(self,loss,label,inputs):
    inputs=Variable(inputs.type(dtype))
    self.dhnext = torch.zeros_like(self.hidden[0])
    self.dy=self.output[27].clone()
        #print(self.dy.shape)
    self.dy[:,int(label[0])]=self.dy[:,int(label[0])]-1
        #print(self.dy.shape)
    self.dwhy += torch.matmul( self.hidden[27].t(),self.dy)
    self.dby += self.dy        
    for t in reversed(xrange(no_time_steps)):
        self.dh = torch.matmul(self.dy,self.why.t()) + self.dhnext # backprop into h  
        self.dhraw = (1 - self.hidden[t] * self.hidden[t]) * self.dh # backprop through tanh nonlinearity          
        self.dbh += self.dhraw #derivative of hidden bias
        self.dwxh += torch.matmul(inputs[:,t,:].t(),self.dhraw) #derivative of input to hidden layer weight
        self.dwhh += torch.matmul( self.hidden[t-1].t(),self.dhraw) #derivative of hidden layer to hidden layer weight
        self.dhnext = torch.matmul(self.dhraw,self.whh.t())            

rnn=RNN(input_size,hidden_size,output_size,batch_size)
def onehot(values,shape):
temp=torch.Tensor(shape).zero_()
for k,j in enumerate(labels):
    temp[k][int(j)]=1
return Variable(temp)

for epoch in range(5):
for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
    images = images.view(-1, no_time_steps, input_size)
    outputs = rnn(images,batch_size,no_time_steps,labels)
    labels = Variable(labels.double())
    output=outputs[27,:,:]
    labelss=onehot(labels,output.shape)
    #print output
    loss=-torch.mul(torch.log(output),labelss.double())
    #print loss
    loss=torch.sum(loss)
    #print(labels)
    rnn.backward(loss,labels,images)
    rnn.updatess(0.01)
    if i==1110:
        break
    if (i+1) % 100 == 0:
        print ('Epoch [%d/%d], Step [%d/%d], Loss: %.4f' 
               %(epoch+1, num_epochs, i+1, len(train_dataset)//batch_size, loss.data[0]))
```

OUTPUT:

Epoch [1/2], Step [100/600], Loss: 714.8081

Epoch [1/2], Step [200/600], Loss: 692.7232

Epoch [1/2], Step [300/600], Loss: 700.1103

Epoch [1/2], Step [400/600], Loss: 698.5468

Epoch [1/2], Step [500/600], Loss: 702.1227

Epoch [1/2], Step [600/600], Loss: 705.9571

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to find a bug in such code. I would suggest simplifying things a little:

1) pytorch takes care of parameters automatically if you do `self.wxh=Parameter` instead of `self.wxh=Variable`, so change all your `Variable` to `Parameter`. And delete your parameter functions.

2) pytorch takes care of the `backward` function automatically if you defined the `forward` function with functions which have a defined `backward` function. So delete your `backward` function in case there is a bug in it.

3) Use `loss=torch.mean(loss)` instead of `loss=torch.sum(loss)` because then your learning rate is independent of batch size.

4) Using `backward` is kind of tricky in pytorch, so use an optimizer instead:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(rnn.parameters(), lr=0.03)

for epoch in range(5):
    ...
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

If after all this, it still doesn't learn. There might be a problem in your RNN. So try to use a pytorch predefined RNN to see if your dataset is even learnable with an RNN.

If doing this solved the problem. You can than undo the above changes one by one, to discover what the problem was.

Comment: Thanks a lot .I will try these changes